# Reloading windows form without closing and reopening

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an windows forms application written in c#. I want to reload form when someone press the "clear" button in it. But I couldn't achieve to call Load event.These lines didn't also work :

```
  this.Refresh();
  this.Load +=new EventHandler(Grafik_Load); // 'Grafik' is the name of the form.
```

What should I do about this? Thanks for helping..

Comment: Application.Restart(); may solve that

Comment: but it will show a flicker (its closing and opening the form) that's what the post was asking to avoid.

Answer (score 5):

Place the 'load' code in a separate function and call that function from you're own code/Load event handler.

Comment: Actually I already have a load function like:

  private void Grafik_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       ....
 }
But I didn't find the correct syntax to call it

Answer (score 4):

```
        private void callonload()
        {
          //code which u wrriten on load event
        }
        private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          callonload();
        }
        private void btn_clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          callonload();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

i found that the hide/show, the show part creates another instance of the same form, so I better dispose the current one, create a new instance of it, and show it.

```
Grafik objFrmGrafik = new Grafik (); 
this.Dispose(); 
objFrmGrafik .Show();
```

Comment: This is the not the exact thing OP asked, he look for do this in same screen.

Answer (score 0):

**Home**  is MDI-Form name. i have tested it.

```
 home.ActiveForm.Dispose();
            home sd = new home();
            sd.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//it is a good idea to use the 'sender' object when calling the form load method 
//because doing so will let you determine if the sender was a button click or something else...

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //you may want to reset any global variables or any other 
    //housekeeping before calling the form load method 
    Form1_Load(sender, e);
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Button)
    {
         //the message box will only show if the sender is a button
         MessageBox.Show("You Clicked a button");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Answers with only code in them tend to get flagged for deletion as they are "low quality".  Please read the help section on answering questions then consider adding some commentary to your Answer.