# Reload a form in MDI

Tags: c#, winforms, mdiparent

I open a form in MDI parent in this way:

```
public partial class MDIParent1 : Form
{
    private void ToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 Form1 = new Form1();
        Form1.MdiParent = this;
        Form1.Show();
    }
}
```

How I will a reload the Form1 in the Form1?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 Form1 = new Form1();
        this.Dispose();
        Form1.MdiParent = new MDIParent1();
        Form1.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you meant by reload Form1?

Comment: The code provided can't work because the object can't dispose itself.  The parent has to.  Which begs the question: what, exactly, are you trying to do?

Comment: At least I think people should vote you up for the use of `Form1` as a variable name which is exactly the class name `Form1`, with this use, we can access all the `instance members` of `Form1` and all the `static class members` of the class `Form1` :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - what I meant is to close the form and open it again

Comment: It doesn't make sense `to close the form and open it again` from the calling form.  Why do you want to do that?  Is it a refresh issue suggested by jth41?

Comment: I just want to reload the form. Clear all changes that happened

Comment: `this.Dispose();` will close/shutdown/destroy/kill the current form and its `message loop`, I guess all the GUI won't be shown any more, normal code can still be executed after `this.Dispose()` but if it shows any GUI, the GUI will be closed immediately (even `ShowDialog()`).

Comment: Create a method `ClearAllData` or something like that and add code that clears the changes. It is not a good idea to close and open the form again for this purpose

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
Form1 Form1 = new Form1();
Form1.MdiParent = this.Parent;
Form1.Show();
this.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean `Refresh` the form?

you can do that by calling a function like this:

```
    public static void LoadAgain()
    {
        Form1.ActiveForm.Refresh();
    }
```

or Perhaps you should continue your search [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725376/reloading-windows-form-without-closing-and-reopening) .